# Issue with 100% height for Sidebar (Panel) in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in trouble when I use Sidebar (Panel) in twitter bootstrap.
Here Is snap of that Sidebar (Panel).

[image]

And Here is my CSS code for it.

```
    .sharecartside .content {
    height: 100% !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 18px 10px 20px 30px;
}
.sharecartside {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 1px 0 0 508px;
}
.sharecartside {
    background: url("../images/bg_sidepannel.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    float: right;
    margin: 1px 0 0 400px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you create live demo (e.g on jsfiddle) for this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make 'height:100%' work for any HTML element, its parent item should have a height value defined. Or the item will expand to height of the nearest ancestor with a height defined.

If all the ancestors of an element have no height defined or defined in percentage, then in order to have the element to expand to the height of the page, you should give both 'body' and 'html' a 100% height.

If you are using bootstrap responsive, using

```
   html,body{ height:100%}
```

in css should solve the problem. Make sure that this rule appear after you includes bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: This doesn't work for me,  I have a panel and it's not stretched to 100% even though I made all ancestor 100% and also body and html. I think min-height should be used too.

Comment: After many tries, I don't see any option but setting the height in px. But I will try to set it in javascript instead.