# Bootstrap's 3.x Panel with 100% height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to css a panel to have 100% height? I tried

```
html,body{ height:100%}
```

and than put `height: 100%` in the panel, without luck.

Comment: Did you Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668392/issue-with-100-height-for-sidebar-panel-in-twitter-bootstrap ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every parent elements must have height: 100%

Answer (score 11):

panel height depends on the content in the panel body, otherwise you have to set the panel body height manually.

```
 <div class="panel-body" style="height:900px">
```

Comment: how would you setup the panel body to take the entire height dynamically?

Comment: _panel height depends on the content in the panel body_ But what if the panel content grows to fit the panel height and it's not 100%? I think that's my current issue

Answer (score 6):

just use `height: 100vh;` if your browser supports CSS3